# Amazon Prime Movies keep stopping and crashing

Tags: video

The movies I watch on Amazon Prime keep stopping and starting until they crash entirely. I get the message that my IPS is too slow.  The icon usually flickers between one and two bars. I have no problem with NETFLIX. My internet server is FIOS.

Comment: So what’s the question?